# Assigning a string to a TextBox.Text property on a form causes a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, textbox, arguments

With this code (listApplications is a ListView control):

```
    private void ShowApplicationPropertiesForm() {
        String FullPath = String.Empty; 
        String Title = String.Empty;
        String Description = String.Empty;
        Boolean Legacy = false;
        Boolean Production = false;
        Boolean Beta = false;
        MyCustomListViewItemDescendant lvi = (MyCustomListViewItemDescendant)listApplications.SelectedItems[0];
        FullPath = lvi.ExePath;
        Title = lvi.Text;
        Description = lvi.ToolTipText;

        ApplicationProperties ap = new ApplicationProperties(
            FullPath,
            Title,
            Description,
            Legacy,
            Production,
            Beta);
        ap.Show();
    }


//overloaded form constructor
public ApplicationProperties(String AFullPath, String ATitle, String ADescription, Boolean ALegacy, Boolean AProduction, Boolean ABeta) {
            this.Text = String.Format("{0} Properties", ATitle);
            textBoxFullPath.Text = AFullPath;
            textBoxTitle.Text = ATitle;
            textBoxDescription.Text = ADescription;
            checkBoxLegacy.Checked = ALegacy;
            checkBoxProduction.Checked = AProduction;
            checkBoxBeta.Checked = ABeta;
        }
```

...I'm getting, "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Stepping through it, the line that bombs is:

```
textBoxFullPath.Text = AFullPath;
```

textBoxFullPath is a Textbox on a form; AFullPath has a valid value of the sort: "Q:\What\AreYou\Gonna\Do\BabyBlue.exe"

Updated:

Partially solved.

It was the old "Premature Assignment" problem. By moving the assignments from the constructor to the Load() event, it no longer bombs (code below).

HOWEVER, now nothing is displaying on the form at runtime...???!?

```
public partial class ApplicationProperties : Form {
        String _fullPath = String.Empty;
        String _title = String.Empty;
        String _description = String.Empty;
        Boolean legacy = false;
        Boolean production = false;
        Boolean beta = false;

        public ApplicationProperties() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ApplicationProperties(String AFullPath, String ATitle, String ADescription, Boolean ALegacy, Boolean AProduction, Boolean ABeta) {
            _fullPath = AFullPath;
            _title = ATitle;
            _description = ADescription;
            legacy = ALegacy;
            production = AProduction;
            beta = ABeta;
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void ApplicationProperties_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //this.Text = String.Format("{0} Properties", _title);          
            Text = String.Format("{0} Properties", _title);
            textBoxFullPath.Text = _fullPath;
            textBoxTitle.Text = _title;
            textBoxDescription.Text = _description;
            checkBoxLegacy.Checked = legacy;
            checkBoxProduction.Checked = production;
            checkBoxBeta.Checked = beta;
        }
```

Updated again:

Adding "InitializeComponent();" to the overloaded constructor did the trick - thanks, SW!

Comment: Where are you initializing `textBoxFullPath`?

Comment: Is your form created with Visual Studio?  If so, you need to add the call to InitializeComponent() to create the TextBox and other UI elements.

Comment: @JJ: You mean to String.Empty? Habit. It probably doesn't help, but I don't see how it could hurt.

Comment: @ClayShannon - I think JJ means where are you instantiating textBoxFullPath (ie, textBoxFullPath = new TextBox();).  This happens in your ApplicationProperties.Designer.cs file within the InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: @Steve Wong: Yes, adding that to the constructor made it work; thanks!

Comment: @JJ and SW: I don't see what you're seeing - I did not write "textBoxFullPath = new..." nor do I see it above. It's true, that it may be in my designer file, but I did not paste that above. If you're seeing it, something "spooky" is going on here...

Comment: @ClayShannon: No problem.  FWIW, I like your solution better (initializing from the Load event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the designer always calls the parameterless constructor, so I've gravitated to no trying to make my own constructors for WinForm Forms.

See my suggestions to tweak below - if you don't get to where you want, let me know and I'll update.

```
    public ApplicationProperties(String AFullPath, String ATitle, String ADescription, Boolean ALegacy, Boolean AProduction, Boolean ABeta)
        : this() // --> Call the parameterless constructor before executing this code
    { 
        _fullPath = AFullPath; 
        _title = ATitle; 
        _description = ADescription; 
        legacy = ALegacy; 
        production = AProduction; 
        beta = ABeta; 
        this.CenterToScreen(); // --> Maybe move this to the Shown event (not sure if you need to)
    }
```

Comment: Actually, adding the ": this() " calling the parameterless constructor caused my assignments not to show up (the controls display, but they have no text in them). It works without it, though.

Comment: i think the thing that actually solves your root problem is just calling InitializeComponent() - I was trying to get you to not have it repeated twice, but it's a fine point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to C#, so please forgive me if I am wrong.

[On MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxw2ez55.aspx), it says that the error you're getting is due to wrong reference, so, in your case, I guess `textBoxFullPath` might not exist (you should check the spelling).

But here, it's something about file streams, and since you're using paths, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/csharpgeneral/thread/b8a3f598-5809-47a2-a4e1-578892f21ff1) may help you. (check the first answer).

Hope it helps.